# How to implement continuous scroll with SingleChildScrollView and GridView in Flutter

Tags: gridview, scroll, scrollview, flutter, flutter-layout

I currently have a SingleChildScrollView as a parent and a GridView as one of the child widgets. Everything is working fine but when the GridView finishes scrolling, the scroll does not pass on to parent ScrollView. In Landscape orientation, the GridView occupies the entire screen so user gets stuck scrolling only the GridView. How can I pass the scroll?

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  controller: _hideButtonController,
  child: Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 80.0), //padding for fab
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        _previousWidgets(),
        _gridWidget(),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 29):

Inside your GridView set physics like this and you are good to go :

```
physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
```

**Edit:**

Doing this can be resource intensive as it generates all the items in a single go instead of inflating/generating items on scrolling, so make sure you don't have large amount of data in your grid or list.

Answer (score 27):

You should use `CustomScrollView` instead of `SingleChildScrollView`.

`CustomScrollView` is a scrollview that can combine multiple type of content. Such as list, grid, or plain widget.

```
CustomScrollView(
  slivers: <Widget>[
    SliverToBoxAdapter(
      child: Container(
        height: 50.0,
        width: double.infinity,
        color: Colors.yellow,
      ),
    ),
    SliverGrid(
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          childAspectRatio: 1.0,
          mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
          crossAxisSpacing: 10.0),
      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
        (context, index) {
          return Container(
            color: Colors.red,
          );
        },
        childCount: 10,
      ),
    ),
    SliverPadding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 80.0),
    )
  ],
),
```

Comment: Add as many SliverToBoxAdapter as you need. wow this is very great

Answer (score 0):

I've answered one similar questions here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76192690/11976596

You can find the same below-

I had a similar issue, where I had a `GridView.builder` inside a `SingleChildScrollView`. Now the problem is you can't create a `GridView` inside `SingleChildScrollView` because both will try to take as much space available which here makes height unbounded/infinte.

So the solution is to wrap the `GridView` with a `SizedBox` and I always prefer to use `GridView.Builder`.

Now the actual question, **"How do I know the size of `SizedBox` when the list is dynamic ?"**

So I wrote this code with a logic to calculate the height of `SizedBox` dynamically based on the `childAspectRatio` attribute of `GridView`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(title: 'Dynamic GridView', home: Home());
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            itemGrid(width),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget itemGrid(double width) {
    const int count = 16;
    const int itemsPerRow = 2;
    const double ratio = 1 / 1;
    const double horizontalPadding = 0;
    final double calcHeight = ((width / itemsPerRow) - (horizontalPadding)) *
        (count / itemsPerRow).ceil() *
        (1 / ratio);
    return SizedBox(
      width: width,
      height: calcHeight,
      child: GridView.builder(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: horizontalPadding),
        itemCount: count,
        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            mainAxisSpacing: 0,
            crossAxisSpacing: 0,
            crossAxisCount: itemsPerRow,
            childAspectRatio: ratio),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return SizedBox(
            child: Card(
              clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                      child: Image.network(
                          "https://picsum.photos/200?${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString()}")),
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0),
                    child: Text(
                      "Lorem Ipsum is a dummy text, lorem ipsum",
                      maxLines: 3,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontSize: 10, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Link to working Dart gist - https://dartpad.dev/?id=05ba8804b19a2978a087c68622000a01

Explanation

- `count` is the total number of items or `itemCount`.
- `itemsPerRow` is the number of items in a row or `crossAxisCount`.
- `ratio` is the `childAspectRatio` attribute of `GridView` that usually is used to set size of an item inside grid. `ratio` is calculated as width/height.
- `horizontalPadding` is the horizontal padding given to `GridView`(in case of vertical list)
- `calcHeight` is the calculated height of the `SizedBox` just so you don't need to give a fixed height in case of dynamic lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can use physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() and shrinkWrap: true inside GridView widget like this

```
SingleChildScrollView(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
      vertical: 16,
      horizontal: 16,
    ),
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Text('Some Text Here'),
        GridView(
          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            crossAxisSpacing: 10,
            mainAxisExtent: 170,
          ),
          children:[],
        ),
     ],),)
```